# how to use webgrid and html helper method on the same view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In asp.net mvc3 project iam using ienumerable view to display collection of object in the webgrid. In the same view i am using html helper methods to create object. i got the error in the helper method "System.collection.generic.ienumerable<...> does not contain definition for <...>"

```
@model IEnumerable<TRADEBLOTTER_MVCPOC.Models.Trader />
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "NewTrader";
}

@{
      var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, 
                             defaultSort: "TradeID",
                             rowsPerPage: 5, fieldNamePrefix: "wg_",
                             canPage: true, canSort: true,
                             pageFieldName: "pg", sortFieldName: "srt" );  
}

<h2>NewTrader</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary()
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <tr>
      <td>
         @Html.LabelFor(t=>t.TraderName,"Trader Name")
      </td>
      <td>
         @Html.TextBoxFor(t=>t.TraderName)
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit Trader" />
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
}
```

Comment: try to remove "Trader Name" see if changes anythink

Answer (score 0):

I think typically you would use something like that in the model above your variable

```
[DisplayName("Trader Name")]
public string TraderName { get; set; }
```

and then your view

```
<h2>NewTrader</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary()
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <tr>
      <td>
         @Html.LabelFor(t=>t.TraderName)
      </td>
      <td>
         @Html.TextBoxFor(t=>t.TraderName)
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit Trader" />
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: use a partial page for the grid (with the IEnumerable version of the model) and another partial page for the individual variables (with the single model).

If the grid is to display information only, and not to edit anything, then bind the grid to a method defined in the model - then there is no need for the view to have an IEnumberable model.

Comment: What I actually ended up doing was not using IEnumerable for the whole page, but just for the control that needed it.